# In ImageMagick, is it possible to -auto-gamma based on a region?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to prepare a set of ~20,000 photos for a timelapse video.  A common problem in timelapse videos is flickering, due to changing lighting conditions, passing clouds, hue changes, etc.

I've used IM to convert each image to greyscale and `-auto-gamma`, which is a drastic improvement in lighting "stability".  Very good, but not yet perfect.
I would now like to do the following, but can't figure out how.

```
1. determine ideal auto gamma based only on the lower 30% of the image
2. apply that ideal gamma to the entire image
```

Each of my images has sky above and buildings below.  The sky changes dramatically as clouds pass by, but the buildings' lighting is fairly stable.

I tried `-region`, but as expected, it only applies the gamma to the region specified.  Is it possible to do what I'm hoping for?  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think so.

You can crop the bottom 30% of the image like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity south -crop x30%+0+0 bottom.jpg
```

so that means you can get the mean of the bottom 30% of the image like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity south -crop x30%+0+0 -format "%[mean]" info:
```

and you can also get the quantum range as well all in one go if you add that in:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity south -crop x30%+0+0 -format "%[mean] %[fx:quantumrange]" info:
```

Now, the gamma is defined as the logarithm of the mean divided by the logarithm of the midpoint of the dynamic range, but we can normalize both these numbers to the range [0-1] as follows:

```
log(mean/quantumrange) / log(0.5)
```

so we'll let `bc` work that out for us like this:

```
echo "scale=4; l($mean30/$qr)/l(0.5)" | bc -l
```

and we can use the result of that to apply a gamma correction to the entire image. So, I have put all that together in a single script, which I call `b30gamma`. You save it under that name and then type:

```
chmod +x b30gamma
```

to make it executable. Then you can run it on an image like this and the result will be saved as `out.jpg` so as not to destroy the input image:

```
./b30gamma input.jpg
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pick up image name as parameter
image=$1

# Get mean of bottom 30% of image, and quantum range (65535 for Q16, or 255 for Q8)
read mean30 qr < <(convert "$image" -gravity south -crop x30%+0+0 -format "%[mean] %[fx:quantumrange]" info:)

# Gamma = log(mean)/log(dynamic range centre point)
gcorr=$(echo "scale=4;l($mean30/$qr)/l(0.5)" | bc -l)

# Debug
echo Image: $image, Mean: $mean30, quantum range: $qr, Gamma: $gcorr

# Now apply this gamma to entire image
convert "$image" -gamma $gcorr out.jpg
```

Comment: I should add that if you have 20,000 images to correct, you could consider using GNU Parallel to get all your CPU cores working in parallel. You would first `mkdir output` to create an output directory, then change the last line of the script so it writes to `"output\$image"` rather than `out.jpg`. Then run `ls *.jpg | parallel -j 8 b30gamma {}` to use 8 CPU cores in parallel.

Comment: It's more like 40,000 by now, so that's even more helpful.  Thanks again.  I wish I could vote for it a dozen more times.